# Hard vector problem

Tags: geometry, vectors

For what α and β the vector $\vec p = \alpha \vec i + 3 \vec j - \beta \vec k$ is collinear to $\vec c$?
$\vec c = (-17, -11, -11)$

Comment: The $\vec j$ component tells you exactly that multiple of $\vec c$ we must try to make $\vec p$ into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the Ansatz $$\vec{p}=\lambda\vec{c}$$ where $\lambda$ is a real number and we get
$$\alpha=-17\lambda$$
$$3=-11\lambda$$
$$-\beta=-11\lambda$$
from the second equation we get
$$\lambda=-\frac{3}{11}$$
now you can compute $$\alpha,\beta$$ we get
$$\alpha=\frac{51}{11},\beta=-3$$

Comment: What about i, j, k?

Comment: $i,j,k$ are unit vectors